# How do I find the max value in only specific columns in a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, row

If this was my dataframe

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 5 | 0.1 |
| 9 | 7 | 8 |
| 1.1 | 2 | 12.9 |

I can use the following code to get the max values in each row... (12) (9) (12.9)

```
df = df.max(axis=1)
```

But I don't know would you get the max values only comparing columns a & b (12, 9, 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one wants to consider only the columns `a` and `b`, and store the maximum value in a new column called `max`, one can do the following

```
df['max'] = df[['a', 'b']].max(axis=1)

[Out]:

      a  b     c   max
0  12.0  5   0.1  12.0
1   9.0  7   8.0   9.0
2   1.1  2  12.9   2.0
```

One can also do that with a custom lambda function, as follows

```
df['max'] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: max(x), axis=1)

[Out]:

      a  b     c   max
0  12.0  5   0.1  12.0
1   9.0  7   8.0   9.0
2   1.1  2  12.9   2.0
```

---

As per [OP's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017801/how-do-i-find-the-max-value-in-only-specific-columns-in-a-row/74017837?noredirect=1#comment130690571_74017837), if one wants to create a new column, `max_of_all`, that one will use to store the maximum value for all the dataframe columns, one can use the following

```
df['max_of_all'] = df.max(axis=1)


[Out]:

      a  b     c   max  max_of_all
0  12.0  5   0.1  12.0        12.0
1   9.0  7   8.0   9.0         9.0
2   1.1  2  12.9   2.0        12.9
```